# oozie ssh action takes long time to complete

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I tried running an ssh action workflow job in oozie with the following action code
Passwordless ssh was configured :

```
   <action name="sshaction">
        <ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
            <command>/bin/bash</command>
         <args>/home/510600/HADOOP_ECO/CDH4/oozietest/test.sh</args>
            <args>first</args>
            <capture-output/> 
        </ssh>
        <ok to="WordCount" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <action name="WordCount">
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <prepare>
                <delete path="${nameNode}/user/510600/output/" />
            </prepare>
            <main-class>${parse_mainClass}</main-class>
            <arg>${inputDir}</arg>
            <arg>${parse_Output}</arg>
        </java>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>
```

Problem I encountered with the above code is oozie ssh action takes long time to complete even with a 2 line shell script, However other action runs very fast.

For the above 2 actions sshaction took 12 mins to complete and the action WordCount took only 15 Seconds to complete

my shellscript is as /home/510600/HADOOP_ECO/CDH4/oozietest/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /home/510600/abc.log
```

Can anyone explain why oozie ssh action takes long time to run ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything works fine except sending status to oozie webserver from shell script, I'nk the issue would be curl.

**Linux utility curl should be present in the remote machine.**

Because oozie webserver internally uses two bash scripts ssh-base.sh and ssh-wapper.sh for executing the commands in remote machine. ssh-base.sh script uses the linux utility curl to send the status back to oozie server by invoking oozie webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it may occurs because of configuration or authenticatin issues.

Did you try executing the script without oozie. How long it takes to complete ?

Comment: I think ssh won't be the issue because ssh runs faster, and machine slowness wont be the issue.                                                                                                  
When I execute the same shell script as the same user(User for oozie server and target machine user are same and both in same machine) using the command (ssh 510600@localhost "/home/sachin/oozietest/test.sh ~/abc.txt"), completed in 0.20 Seconds

Comment: Ok. then ssh server might not be the issue.

Did your machine overloaded the time in which you  run the job ?

Comment: No, machine was not overloaded. When I enabled logging in shell script, I was able to find the fact - shell script triggered by oozie is getting completed in 1 second. But still oozie server takes 15 mins to complete.